# Gson crush in app compiled from PlayStore

Tags: java, json, api, android-studio, gson

I have developed an app to read json API

I used Gson library to serialize json.

In debug and run mode with emulator and device linked to android studio, it run;

If I create bundle and I publish in Play Store, it crush when try to convert fromJson.

I don't know what check to fix the issue....

This is the code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
ClResult MyResult = new ClResult(); 
MyResult = gson.fromJson(response, ClResult.class);
```

This is the returned json:

```
{"Success":true,"Message":"","Content":"W3siSUQiOjUsImNsY19jb2"}
```

This is the ClResult class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ClResult {

@SerializedName("Success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;

@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String message;

@SerializedName("Content")
@Expose
private String content;

public Boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace? Your code and json look fine at first glance.

Comment: Sorry, where do I find it due that debugging it is all ok? Only app compiled and downloaded from PlayStore crush... I should get it from device when run app downloaded

Comment: I don't have stacktrace, I only see that it crush if app downloaded from PlayStore

Comment: Hi everyone...Nobody?

Answer (score 0):

Need to set in gradle:

```
            minifyEnabled false 
            shrinkResources false
```

Regards